# I have the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" on line 20

Tags: python, list

---

### line 20, in 
mayor=float(promtemp[0])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

it gives me that error what am I doing wrong?

```
nombrepais=[]
temperatura=[]

for x in range (4):
    nombre=input("ingrese el nombre del pais:")
    nombrepais.append(nombre)
    temp1=int(input("ingrese la temperatura media mensual de enero:"))
    temp2=int(input("ingrese la temperatura media mensual de febrero:"))
    temp3=int(input("ingrese la temperatura media mensual de marzo:"))
    temperatura.append([temp1,temp2,temp3])

for x in range (4):
    print(nombrepais[x],temperatura[x][0],temperatura[x][1],temperatura[x][2])
 
for x in range (4):
    promtemp=(temperatura[x][0] + temperatura[x][1] + temperatura[x][2])/3
    print(nombrepais[x],promtemp)

tempmayor=0
mayor=promtemp[0]
for x in range(1,4):
    if promtemp[x]>mayor:
        mayor=promtemp[x]
        tempmayor=x

print("el pais con mayor temperatura media trimestral es ")
print(nombrepais(tempmayor))
print("con un total de", mayor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign a `float` to `promtemp` 4 lines earlier, in the `for` loop. As the error says, you cannot index into a `float`.

Comment: so I have to add a float after the equal in the third cycle?

Comment: `promtemp` is already a float, so I don't know why you're indexing it in the `mayor` assignment. Do you want `promtemp` to be a float or a list?